# Mysql otimizar Query

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, otimização

```
SELECT data_envio,
       nota_fiscal,
       nome_cliente,
       modelo.nome,
       conteudo.quantidade
  FROM conteudo,
       equipamento,
       caixa,
       pedido,
       cliente,
       modelo
 WHERE pedido.numero_pedido = conteudo.numero_pedido
   AND cliente.idcliente = pedido.cliente_idcliente
   AND modelo.idmodelo = conteudo.modelo_idmodelo
 LIMIT 20,40
```

### [image: Amostra da resposta do SQL]

Esclarecendo que determinadas tabelas tem dezenas de milhares de registros.

1. Primeiramente, quero me informa, sobre algum modificador capaz da intenção de delimitar um trecho do banco de dados a ser processado, definindo a linha inicial e linha final.
   Que saiba, o modificador LIMIT executa no final do processamento e não satisfaz esse objetivo.
2. Outra necessidade, é que agrupar a repetição dos produtos (coluna nome) e somar a quantidade. Observe na tabela que temos para uma nota fiscal em comum, linhas com repetição do produto.
3. Necessita apresentar até o limite de 200 registros ou menos, desde que mostre a ultimas linhas um conjunto completo da mesma nota fiscal (Ou seja, não pode apresentar dados parciais para um numero de nota fiscal).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A linguagem SQL não dispõe de mecanismos que delimite um trecho do banco de dados a ser processado, o que você pode utilizar é uma cláusula onde estipule valores de campos a serem considerados (o que não necessariamente corresponde a "trecho do banco de dados" em seu entendimento usual). O item 2 é conseguido com a utilização da cláusula GROUP BY e a função de agregação SUM, consulte a documentação do SGBD Pelo que entendi de seu item 3 você teria que implementar em sua aplicação..

Comment: Acredito que faltam explicações da estrutura do seu banco de dados e do objetivo da sua `query`. Sem saber qual o conjunto de dados que você necessita e ter um exemplo executável, fica praticamente impossível te ajudar

Comment: Note que suas tabelas `equipamento` e `caixa` constam da cláusula FROM mas não possuem condições de junção na cláusula WHERE, o que acarreta um produto cartesiano, que, não me parece, ser o que deseja. Estude como fazer junções.

Comment: Acredito que dá para resolver o seu problema criando Views.